# Why not available $scope.value of the variable in runtime?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

Why not available $scope.reserved of the variable in runtime? In template {{reserved}} is ок, but in controller value = undefibed.

I have the following code

**Service:**

```
'use sctict'

angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .service('api', ['$http', '$q', function api($http, $q) {
        var server = 'http://localhost/ires-api';
        var jsondata = {
            getReservedHours: function (masters, date) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url: server + '/reservations/' + masters + '/' + date, cache:true})
                    .success(function(response) {
                        //return response;
                        deferred.resolve({
                             data: response
                             });
                        }).error(function(msg, code) {
                          deferred.reject(msg);
                          $log.error(msg, code);
                        });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
        }
        return jsondata;
    }]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.click = function(){
     masters = [5,51];
     api.getReservedHours(masters,  '2007/08/27').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.reserved = response.data;
        });

        console.log($scope.reserved); // undefined ....
}
```

Comment: the only place `$scope.reserved` appears in the code shown is when you try to log it. You are also trying to log it outside of the promise callback and the AJAX request hasn't completed then

Comment: I tried to use the promise. I thought it would work in this case?

Comment: thought what would work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the assignment?

```
 api.getReservedHours(masters,  '2007/08/27').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.reserved = response.data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "getReservedHours" is an asynchronous request and $scope.reserved is undefined (because the request is not complete) when you print it. Use this code instead

```
    $scope.click = function(){
         masters = [5,51];
         api.getReservedHours(masters,  '2007/08/27').then(function(response) {
                        $scope.reserved = response.data;
                        console.log($scope.reserved);  // This would work
            });

            console.log($scope.reserved); // undefined ....
    }
```